# NuxtJS and Vue2 Can I write server side code for Recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, recaptcha

I recently picked up NuxtJS en Vue to write a blog and wish to add a Google Recaptcha.

The best validation is a server side validation obviously. So before users can submit the form, the back-end needs to verify the google recaptcha response. I was wondering if I could do this through my Nuxt-app itself?

So instead of having a method that validates if there is a recaptcha response, I was wondering if I can write something in a special hook(maybe validate()?) that is unavailable from bots on the clientside but still checks if the recaptcha response is valid. Before sending the form.

Is this possible, is yes/no how and why not? Please enlighten me!

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it might be possible to validate the Recapthca key on the frontend, but since you need to use your private key to do so, your private key would be exposed.

Also it shouldn't be the frontend's decision whether or not to submit the form based on a Recaptcha. The frontend should submit the form - and the backend should decide how to handle the submission based on the Recaptcha result. Otherwise bots would still be able to hit the endpoint.

Comment: Well with google recaptcha google takes care of the backend, but writing a 'if succes=== true' feels like something that a bot can just turn into true whenever it feels like it. Or am I overestimating what bots are capable of in clientside JS?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how the Recaptcha flow should work. Your client should get a token from Google using your public key. This token should be sent with the form content to your backend. The backend should then validate said token using your private key.

If you don't validate on your backend, the "bot" can just hit your endpoint and your backend has no way to know if the request is from a real user or a bot - and therefore no way knowing how to handle it.